# overlay and buffer content

Tags: overlays

I provide `web-mode-column-show` in [web-mode.el](http://web-mode.org) to display a column that "connects" the start tag and the end tag.

This column may cross empty lines. In that case I use `(move-to-column COL t)` (see the `t` arg) to put the overlay at the right column. The problem is that, doing so, I modify the buffer content (I add spaces).

Is there a way to display an overlay at a specific line/column where no "content" exists ?

Comment: You want to look at `vline.el` and `fill-column-indicator.el`.  It is called an `after-string` overlay, and it is combined with a filler (spacer).  `fill-column-indicator` is a better example (in my opinion):  https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator  There is also an alignment with a particular column in the `fill-column-indicator` source code.  I based my minor mode on that concept, which is a vertical line that tracks the cursor position.

Comment: Here is a link to a quick simple example that does what you want -- it was written at the beginning of my quest:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23707953/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reprint of the example referred to in the comment above:

```
(save-excursion
  (end-of-line)
  (let ((eol-floating-column (+ (current-column) 10)))
    (overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point))
                 'after-string
                 (concat
                  (propertize (char-to-string ?\uE001)
                              'display
                              `((space :align-to ,eol-floating-column)
                                (space :width 0)))
                  (propertize (char-to-string ?\u00B6)
                              'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black")
                              'cursor t) ))))
```

Comment: I've implemented my need this way: when the indicator is before ```eol``` I use a standard overlay and when the indicator should go beyond ```eol``` I put the overlay at the end of the line and attach the ```'after-string``` property

Comment: You are correct.  There is even a `before-string` for something to the left of the margin, like `linum-mode` uses.   I'm glad it worked out for your needs.